# How to create a function similar to MorphologicalComponents?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

As everyone knows, `MorphologicalComponents` can create a list that shows only the difference between morphological clusters. But sometimes we need to find out the morphological properties as well as the original values.

For example:

```
l={{1,1,0,2,3},{1,2,0,2,2},{2,2,2,3,3}};

MorphologicalComponents[l,CornerNeighbors->False]
(*{{1,1,0,1,1},{1,1,0,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1}}*)
```

But of course that's not what I want. I would like to have a result like this:

```
{{1,1,0,2,3},{1,4,0,2,2},{4,4,4,5,5}}
```

There're several attemps, but none of them are satisfying. Are there any other elegant solutions?

---

My algorithm will require multiple `MorphologicalComponents` calculation, thus be quite slow in speed when there are a lot of diffenent values in a huge list.

So, I would like to have a solution requires only one calculation and be as fast as possible while as simple as possible (No fussying with `Compile` if the code is too long......)

Answer (score 1):

Though I was not able to run your code, I thought my solution might be useful for you (as I think it runs a bit faster):

```
Clear[mylabeling];
mylabeling[list_List] := 
  Module[{maxlist = Max@list, temp, tempmap, lut},
   temp = Map[MorphologicalComponents[
        Image[ImageData@Binarize[Image@list, {#, #}]], 
        CornerNeighbors -> False] &, Range[maxlist]];
   tempmap = Map[FromDigits[Reverse@#, maxlist] &, 
     Transpose[temp, {3, 1, 2}], {2}];
   lut = Table[0, {Max@tempmap}];
   lut[[Union@Flatten@tempmap]] = 
    Range[0, -1 + Length@Union@Flatten@tempmap, 1];
   Return[Map[lut[[#]] &, tempmap, {2}]];
  ];
```

Calling

```
mylabeling@{{1, 1, 0, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 0, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 3, 3}}
```

gives

```
{{1, 1, 0, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 0, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 5, 5}}
```

This is not strictly identical to what you have written above, but I think the essence of your problem is simply to split all levels of your integer valued input list, so the order of resulting labels should not matter. I did not do extensive testing, let me know if it works for you. Also, `ParallelMap` might be useful when doing the `MorphologicalComponents` mapping. There is no useful solution without multiple calls of this built-in function. However, I am sure that a more effective way would be to implement a special solution of the flood-fill algorithm, but this seems to be beyond your intention.

Comment: Er, sorry for the late reply, but I suppose your method is almost identical to mine? We all used multiple `MorphologicalComponents`. Maybe a neat implementation of flood-fill algorithm will be great~

Comment: My original code still have some bugs inside, so I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

The output of my function is slightly different from the one you give, but I think it still meets your requirement?:

```
unitStepExpand = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand@# &;

help = Function[{x, a}, #] &@unitStepExpand@If[x == a, 1, 0];

label[l_] := Module[{element = l // Flatten // Union // Rest, layer, coloredlayer},
  layer = MorphologicalComponents[#, CornerNeighbors -> False] &@help[l, #] & /@ element;
  coloredlayer = FoldList[Max@# (1 - UnitStep[-#] &)@#2 + #2 &, layer];
  Total@coloredlayer]

l = {{1, 1, 0, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 0, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 3, 3}}; 
l // label // TraditionalForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: yeah, this code is valid, but it still calls `MorphologicalComponents` Multiple times, can one aviod multiple calls to it?

Comment: @wjx It's beyond my reach. I searched in the document for a while but didn't find any proper function, and I don't know any existing algorithm that can be used for the task.